# A date is entered in TextBox how to code to return ddmmyyyy format

Tags: c#, string-formatting

When I enter date in text box like this:   `2/2/1998`

Iwant my date to appear like this

```
02021998
```

`ToShortDateString()` return like this: `02/2/1998`

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: Something like `DateTime.Parse(textBox.Text).ToString("MMddyyyy")`?

Comment: It might be good if you could unambiguify whether it's monthday or daymonth.

Comment: As an aside, why aren't you using a `DateTimePicker`?

Answer (score 2):

You can give format in `ToString()`, you can find more about Date formats over [**here**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse("2/2/1998", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string dateString = date.ToString("ddMMyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

> The [`invariant culture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx) is culture-insensitive; it is associated
>   with the English language but not with any country/region. You specify
>   the invariant culture by name by using an empty string ("") in the
>   call to a CultureInfo instantiation method.
>   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture also retrieves an instance of the
>   invariant culture. It can be used in almost any method in the
>   System.Globalization namespace that requires a culture. The objects
>   returned by properties such as CompareInfo, DateTimeFormat, and
>   NumberFormat also reflect the string comparison and formatting
>   conventions of the invariant culture.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
myDateTime.ToString("MMddyyyy"); //if you want month first
myDateTime.ToString("ddMMyyyy"); //if you want day first
```

Answer (score 0):

You first have to parse it to a `DateTime`:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse("2/2/1998");
```

Then you can use `ToString` with the custom format:

```
string str = dt.ToString("ddMMyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

However, it's not the best sample since it's not clear what the month is and what the day.